# JQuery - ASP.NET - Get the value of radio buttons and tally

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I need to recreate a simple JS page that is taking radio button values for yes and no questions and displaying the results of what was selected, Unfortunately ASP.NET is blocking the way... Anyone know how to get around the problem of net being able to get the values correctly in .NET, with no back end?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function scoreQuiz(form) {

    var count = 0;

    if ($('#<%=rbYesOne.ClientID%> radio:selected').val() == "1") {
        alert("YES");
    }

    if ($('#<%=rbNoOne.ClientID%> radio:selected').val() == "0") {
        alert("NO");
    } 

    else {
        alert("FU......");           
    }
</script>

<div class="row">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbYesOne" value="1" runat="server" GroupName="Question1" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbNoOne" value="0" runat="server" GroupName="Question1" />
     <!-- and twelve more... -->
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var rbYesOne = document.getElementById('<%=rbYesOne.ClientID%>');
    var rbNoOne = document.getElementById('<%=rbNoOne.ClientID%>');
    /* and twelve more...*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a radio button is checked, select it with the `:checked` filter, then see if any results were found with the length property:

```
if ($('#<%=rbYesOne.ClientID%>:checked').length === 0) {
    alert("NO");
}
```

Or use the `is` function:

```
if ($('#<%=rbYesOne.ClientID%>').is(":checked")) {
    alert("NO");
}
```

Also, working around asp.net auto-generated IDs can be a pain.  To make life easier you can give the radio buttons unique **class names**, and then do simply:

```
if ($('.rbOne:checked').length === 0) {
   alert("NO");
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you Adam. I had tried length, with no luck, but .is() call worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$("#<%=rbYesOne.ClientID%>").change(function() {
    alert("YES");
});

$("#<%=rbNoOne.ClientID%>").change(function() {
    alert("NO");
});
```